# My laptop seems to have issues with the new router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns

We just installed a new optical modem/router/ap, and it doesn’t like my laptop.
At first I thought it was a dns problem because the default dns server was the router itself, but after changing to 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4 it still had issues. Sometimes it wouldn’t be able to even ping googles ip address. Another oddity is that the router would refuse any connections to itself coming from my laptop (ie can’t open up it’s admin panel) even after trying wired, wireless both directly and through a different router connected to it.
This issue only happens to my laptop, all other devices on the network seem to be fine.
I’m running manjaro linux on gnome.

Comment: Try to factory reset the router, or find a firmware update (by the manufacturer).

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon -

1. Make sure the Router and Laptop are running on the latest firmware (router) - Drivers (laptop)  - if you're new router is WiFi 6 - There are/were issues with early drivers for the WiFi 6 (802.11AX) system that would cause random WiFi connections Drops -
2. If you have 2 routers (previous & new) powered up and running on your network - you need to make sure that the previous router is not configure to be a router. No WAN and no DHCP -
3. If you used the same WiFi configured (SSID names and passwords) there could be some connection issues if modification were done on the laptop side. Like setting your laptop up with a static IP - I Do recommend clearing all known (rememberedd) WiFi connection from the computers memory as an annual or semi-annual practice
   Windows 10 Steps = Start>Settings>Network & Internet>Wi-Fi> Click "Manage Known Networks" - Remove any duplicates and/or trouble connection and then reconnect as if you're connecting to the WiFi for the 1st time.

When you do reply, please include some key information like router/laptop manufacturer and OS/Firmware versions. One device or many devices being used and how many have a problem. Hopefully this puts you on the path to resolving your connectivity issues.

From the Top!!

T...